# Pragma syntax in Haskell

Tags: haskell, syntax, pragma

```hs
module Practice where

{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

class TooMany a where 
  tooMany :: a -> Bool

instance TooMany Int where
   tooMany n = n > 42 

newtype Goats =
  Goats Int deriving (Eq, Show)

--What I load into the playground
tooMany (Goats 17)

--the error I get: " No instance for (TooMany Goats) arising from a use of ‘tooMany’ "
```

I believe that this code should work but is not working because I am using Haskell For Mac which may use different notation for pragmas.

Comment: I think you forgot to add `TooMany` in the `deriving` clause.

Comment: As far as I know, the pragmas have to go at the very top of the file, before the module declaration.

Comment: When I add `TooMany` in the deriving clause I get the error: " Can't make a derived instance of ‘TooMany Goats’:
    ‘TooMany’ is not a stock derivable class (Eq, Show, etc.) "

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use [**`GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving`**](https://limperg.de/ghc-extensions/#generalizednewtypederiving), you still need to specify what instances you want to "borrow" from the wrapped type in the `deriving` clause, so you define the `Goat` type with:

```
newtype Goats = Goats Int deriving (Eq, Show, TooMany)
```

Note that, like [@RobinZigmond says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60938122/how-do-i-use-pragmas-in-haskell-for-mac/60938247#comment107811820_60938122), you need to define the pragmas at the top of the file, so:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

module Practice where

class TooMany a where 
  tooMany :: a -> Bool

instance TooMany Int where
   tooMany n = n > 42 

newtype Goats = Goats Int deriving (Eq, Show, TooMany)
```

In GHCi, we can then query, for example:

```
*Practice> tooMany (Goats 12)
False
```

Although I did this experiment on a Linux machine, I would be very surprised that a this does not work on a different platform. Especially since such language extensions have not much to do with the platform they run on. Language extensions are usually platform-indepdent, hence like [@DanielWagner says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60938122/pragma-syntax-in-haskell/60938247?noredirect=1#comment107812132_60938247), adding the type class in the `deriving` should be done on all platforms.

Comment: This works. Thank you. In using Haskell for Mac I have been weary cause it does have a few quirks. I changed the post title though to avoid confusion for future viewers.

Comment: Everything said in this answer applies to Haskell for things that are not Mac, too.

Comment: @DanielWagner Haskell For Mac is an application

Comment: @LeapyNick I am aware of that fact; additionally, my previous comment still stands true.

Comment: @LeapyNick Haskell For Mac should have absolutely no programming language-level differences from GHC Haskell, since it *uses* GHC (which is, by far, the most popular Haskell compiler).